# Kindle fire menu icons

Tags: android, themes, kindle

I'm using light theme for my Android app:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"  ...
```

It runs at many different devices, including Kindle Fire. The menu bar (or "Action bar") in Kindle Fire is always has black background, so my icons becomes invisible here. I have additional set of icons for Kindle. Where should I put it (is there some kind of predefined folder name?) or how can I indicate, that this icons I should use for Kindle, and that for the rest of devices.

Now I have drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-xhdpi, where I place all my icons and images. How should I change the structure to add light icons for Kindle? Or may be I can make the menu bar in Kindle with light background?

Comment: You could just creat your action bar with actionbar sherlock. Then it wont get changed on the kindle